# Constant length string of numbers and letters

Tags: string, excel, numbers, vba

I'd like to search for errors in a column of strings that have the same length an format :(example: `B2013JMSL10764`, `B2013JMSL11030`).

by errors I mean having letters where numbers are supposed to be and the other way around, example : the letter `O` instead of number `0`.

is it possible to find all strings with errors and copy them into a new column but same row where they were found.

Thanks. I'd appreciate any suggestion to how shall I approach this problem, or possibly some tips and code lines that I will need.

this is what I have so far:

```
Sub sampleNoCheck()

    Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    Dim uColumn As String

    ' if your data is in a different column then change A to some other letter(s)
    uColumn = "j"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Range
    For i = 2 To Range(uColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(uColumn & i)

        {Dim part1 As String, part2 As Integer, part3 As String, part6 As String, part7 As String, part8 As String, part4 As Integer

        If Len(r) = 14 Then
            part1 = Left(r, 1)
            part2 = Mid(r, 2, 5)
            part3 = Mid(r, 6, 6)
            part6 = Mid(r, 7, 7)
            part7 = Mid(r, 8, 8)
            part8 = Mid(r, 9, 9)
            part4 = Right(r, 5)

        ElseIf Len(r) = 15 Then 'possibility of having an extra text digit 
            Dim part5 As String
            part1 = Left(r, 1)
            part2 = Mid(r, 2, 5)
            part3 = Mid(r, 6, 6)
            part6 = Mid(r, 7, 7)
            part7 = Mid(r, 8, 8)
            part8 = Mid(r, 9, 9)
            part4 = Mid(r, 10, 14)
            part5 = Right(r, 1)
        Else
            MsgBox "error in row " & i
        End If

        If IsText(part1) = true And IsNumber(part2) = True And IsText(part3) = True And IsText(part6) = True And IsText(part7) = True And IsText(part8) = True And IsNumber(part5) = True And (part5 = d Or part5 = e Or part5 = f) Then

    Next i

    Else
        MsgBox "error in row " & i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this meant to be done with vba in excel?

Comment: which technology are you using?

Comment: Hi, what have you got so far?  Can you show us some code?

Comment: @npst Yes Im planning on organizing this column of dta in excel, it contains 1500 rows of data ideally.

Comment: @msturdy Sorry Im still not sure how to aprach this problem and have no code done so far.

Comment: @Sachin Im planning on using MS excel

Comment: @user3198740 OK, so start by doing some reading about looping through columns in VBA in Excel, there are a lot of tutorials online :)

Comment: @msturdy after reading last night i came up with the code shown above, still im getting an error saying that istext(part1) isn't defined, if i remove it says that isnumber(part2) isnt defined what did i do wrong can you help me please

Comment: @user3198740 your code isn't very clearly formatted.. I've tried to clear it up a little, and I don't understand all the `part1 = Left(r, 1)` bits.. what is the aim of those sections?

Comment: @msturdy I split the string B 2013 JMSL 10764 into part1:B Part2:2013 part3,6,7,8:J,M,S, andL respectivly part4:10764 then a possiblilty of an aditional text charecter (D, E ,or F) which is part5  I split text into seperate letters since i didnt find  a way to make sure it's text other  than checking letter by letter unlike numbers with isnumber() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry my post wasn't proffesional, I finally could put a messy code together wich does most of the job the following code checks for mistakes and provides feedback in case of errors found:

```
Sub sampleNoCheck()

Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    Dim uColumn As String

    ' if your data is in a different column then change A to some other letter(s)
    uColumn = "A"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Range
For i = 2 To Range(uColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(uColumn & i)
Dim part1 As String, part2 As String, part3 As String, part6 As String, part7 As String, part8 As String, part4 As Integer, part5 As String
If Len(r) = 14 Then
part1 = Left(r, 1)
part2 = Mid(r, 2, 4)
part3 = Mid(r, 6, 1)
part6 = Mid(r, 7, 1)
part7 = Mid(r, 8, 1)
part8 = Mid(r, 9, 1)
part4 = Right(r, 5)

ElseIf Len(r) = 15 Then

part1 = Left(r, 1)
part2 = Mid(r, 2, 4)
part3 = Mid(r, 6, 1)
part6 = Mid(r, 7, 1)
part7 = Mid(r, 8, 1)
part8 = Mid(r, 9, 1)
part4 = Mid(r, 10, 5)
part5 = Right(r, 1)

Else: MsgBox "Insuffficient number of code digits in row " & i
End If
If IsNumeric(part1) = False And IsNumeric(part2) = True And IsNumeric(part3) = False And IsNumeric(part6) = False And IsNumeric(part7) = False And IsNumeric(part8) = False And IsNumeric(part4) = True And (part5 = D Or part5 = E Or part5 = F Or part5 = Null) Then
GoTo nextiteration
Else
MsgBox "error " & i
End If
nextiteration:
Next i

End Sub
```